# Should I write back end code for image processing App in Android?

Tags: android, image-processing

I need to write an app which takes pictures of some forms and converts them to a table filled with information. For that I need to do some image processing but not sure if I can do this on a normal phone or if I need to write backend code such as in Python, and do the processing in a server and then give back the data to the Phone. What is optimal in this case?

Answer (score 1):

There's no correct answer, it all depends on what are your goals and constraints you're working with.

Processing image on BE:

**PRO:**
 - the Android app will be pretty easy
 - the processing can be pretty advanced since you basically don't have to worry about hardware limit. Obviously, this depends on the number of users and the number of servers you have

**CONS:**
- you use bandwidth to pass this information. In particular, uploading the pictures can be problematic if the user is running on the data plan, it could discourage him from using your app.

Processing Image client-side:

**PRO**
- you don't use the internet connection, so your app can even work offline

**CONS**
- hardware can be pretty limited, especially in terms of memory available for the app to run. When dealing with images it's very easy to run into memory problems and have performance issues in the app

Answer (score 1):

You can do that native, using C++ or using GPU which is more faster than native. It depends what kind of processing you want to do.